# Unix : WildCard SubString Search between XML Tags

Tags: xml, linux, shell, unix

I have a huge Log file of XML of web services request and responses.
Each Web Service has a Request tag common like below

```
<s:Envelope ......Some tags before Request tag <xyzServiceRequest>Request Data   </xyzServiceRequest></s:Body></s:Envelope>


<s:Envelope ....Some more tags before Request tag <abcServiceRequest xmlns="urn" >Request Data  of another service </abcServiceRequest></s:Body></s:Envelope>

<s:Envelope ...Few more tags before request <defServiceRequest xmlns="urn" /> </s:Body></s:Envelope>
```

Using Unix Commands , I want to extract the Service Request name only from above data.

Output should be like :

**xyzServiceRequest**

**abcServiceRequest**

**defServiceRequest**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
grep -o '<[^</]*ServiceRequest'    YourLogFile  | sed 's/<//'
```

Comment: Used this to avoid duplicate results `grep -o '<[^</]*ServiceRequest'    YourLogFile  | sed 's/<//' | awk '!seen[$0]++' `

Comment: @arun kumar:  interesting.  I would have done a   '| sort | uniq' but that would add a N log N cost.  The nice thing about '| sort | uniq' is that it is easy to add a uniq -c and get a count of occurrences.    I am sure that you could do this with awk as well.